# Ignite Server Node Crashes On throwing user defined exceptions from the cache store

Tags: ignite

I am using **Ignite.Net** and In my use case I have one server node and one client node. I have enabled 3rd party persistence, both for ReadThrough and WriteThrough modes.
In my cache store implementation on the server node, i.e in load(), Write() and delete() functions of the cache store, I am throwing user defined exception when I get a unexpected result from my database operation.
But when an user defined exception is thrown at the server node following are my observations.

1: When PutIfAbsentAsync() or ReplaceAsync() function is called from the client node,which results in a Write() function on the cache store on the server node : An **Unhandled Exception** is thrown on the server node and server node just **Crashes**, While these functions still return **true** as a result on the client node. Which I think is an incorrect behavior.

2: When TryGetAsync is called from the client node, which results in a Load() on the cache store : An **Unhanded Exception** is thrown on the server node and an **IgniteException** on the client node. Which I think is excepted behavior, Please correct me if I am wrong ?

Comment: Please provide full exception stack traces.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have reproducer ready?

Either way, I recommend filing a ticket against [Apache Ignite JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/IGNITE/issues).

There was a recent discussion about unwanted node terminations due to uncatched erros, which might be related to this issue.